# Ms access error 2465

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm getting the error 2465 on the below code. when i create sql-pass through query in MS Access.Please let me know whet will be the possibility for the error

[1-form].Form.RecordSource="select * from querydef 1=0;"

Comment: I don't understand. Is `querydef` a pass through query that already works? Or are you trying to create it?  `select * from querydef WHERE 1=0` would be valid SQL, if you want to return no records.

Comment: i have created a new querydef which returns only the columns without the records.But when i use the [1-form].Form.RecordSource="select * from querydef 1=0;" code it throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Pass-Through query with VBA see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/112108)

```
     Dim mydatabase As Database, myquerydef As QueryDef

     Set mydatabase = CurrentDB
     Set myquerydef = mydatabase.CreateQueryDef(SPTQueryName)

     myquerydef.Connect = ConnectString
     myquerydef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM querydef WHERE 1=0"
     myquerydef.Close
```

Still not sure what the form has to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It should read:

```
[1-form].RecordSource="select * from querydef where 1=0;"
```

But if querydef returns zero records, you can also use:

```
[1-form].RecordSource="select * from querydef;"
```